# firebug: "no element found" error when doing a jquery ajax call to an ashx handler

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ashx

Each of my calls to an ashx handler is causing me to get the "no element found" error in Firefox but my website does not crash when performing calls to that handler. I also get a "HierarchyRequestError:Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy". Below is the code that is giving me those two errors:

```
 $.post("checkout_model.ashx?a=CheckSession", function (data) {
                    // if session is still available
                    alert(data);
                    if ($.trim(data).length > 0) {
                        $.post("checkout_model.ashx?a=SaveAddress", $("#addressdetails").serialize(), function (data) {
                            $("#addressresult p.result").remove();
                            $("#addressresult").prepend(data);
                        });
                        storeCookies();
                        // update orderdetails
                        $.post("checkout_model.ashx?a=GetCartContent", function (data) {
                            $("#orderdetails").html(data);
                        });
                        var address = $("#AddressLine1").val();
                        if ($("#AddressLine2").val() != "") address += ", " + $("#AddressLine2").val();
                        address += ", " + $("#Suburb").val();
                        $("#tabaddress").text("Step 1: Modify Address: " + address);
                        $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", 1);
                        $("#tabaddress").addClass("modifyaddress");
                        $("#tabpayment").removeClass("disabled"); // enable step 3
                    } else {
                        $("#addressdetails").html("<p class='error'>Your order has timed out. You will need to <a href='viewcart.aspx'>select the items</a> to purchase again.</p>")
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Not enough information, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ajax response includes a "Content-Type" header with the value "text/xml", Firefox expects the response to be valid XML with a single root element. If it is not, Firefox issues the "no element found" error.

As for the second error, it may be that in either of the following lines the value of "data" is not valid HTML or contains tags like `<html>` or `<body>`:

```
$("#addressresult").prepend(data);

$("#orderdetails").html(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, checked the response and in fact because the ashx handler did not return any data, it caused firefox to throw those "no element found" errors. The second error got resolved after i fixed the first by writing data to the response.

Comment: I got this error even though my response did not include a `Content-Type` header, so I guess Firefox just doesn't like empty responses (Chrome and IE never complained). I changed my server code to return `"success"` (with JSON content type) and the error is now gone.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `responseType` request.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '...', true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
```

See this for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

Comment: Stack Overflow utilizes English to communicate between users. I've translated your request as best I could. You may be interested in our [Portuguese version of Stack Overflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) though.